# Model Sum of Squares from ANOVA table

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, experiment-design, model, sum

**Background:** I am studying a course on statistical experiments using the textbook by Douglas Montgomery on the analysis of experiments. This is an introductory course and so I am relatively new to the study of these types of models.

**Question:** Consider the model $Y_{i,j,k} = \mu + R_i + C_j + T_k + \epsilon_{i,j,k}$ where $R_i$ is the impact of from row $i$, $C_j$ is the impact from column $j$ and $T_k$ is the impact from treatment $k$ where there are exactly $n$ rows, $n$ columns, and $n$ treatments. We know that the row sum of squares $S^2_{\text{row}} = \sum _ {i=1}^n \frac{Y_{i \cdot \cdot}^2}{n} - \frac{Y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}^2}{n^2}$ and similarly for $S^2_{\text{column}}$ and $S^2_{\text{treatment}}$ we have the same form but instead we sum over $j$ and $k$ respectively from $1$ to $n$ (we take the formulae for the sums of squares directly from the corresponding ANOVA table).

I have read in the textbook (without justification) the formula for the expected value $ \color{red}{\mathbb{E}(S^2_{\text{row}}\space)}$ and (again) the same applies for the columns and treatments by replacing $R_i^2$ with $C_j^2$ (for the columns) and $T_k^2$ (for the treatments).

$\text{How do we find the formula for the expectation?}$

*Note: we are making the standard modelling assumptions for these types of models where the error terms are independent and normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.*

Comment: Plug $Y_{i..}$ and $Y_{...}$ into $S_{\text{row}}^2$ and do the algebra.

Comment: It's easier to work with the centered form of $S_R^2$ (compared with my first comment, although it should also work, but more verbosely), as User1865345's answer shows.  In DoE, using orthogonality between effects always helps.

Comment: By "orthogonality between effects", I mean all the terms inside parentheses of the decomposition $y_{ijk} - \bar{y}_{...} = (\bar{y}_{i..} - \bar{y}_{...}) + (\bar{y}_{.j.}  - \bar{y}_{...}) + (\bar{y}_{..k} - \bar{y}_{...}) + (y_{ijk} - \bar{y}_{i..} - \bar{y}_{.j.} - \bar{y}_{..k} + 2\bar{y}_{...})$ are orthogonal.  Using this fact, it is easy to derive all the sum of squares in the ANOVA table and compute expected mean of sum squares.

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning of the bar notation? I'm not quite following this explanation or the answer as the notation seems to be slightly different from that which I'm familiar with @Zhanxiong

Comment: Your textbook should have the bar notation, basically, bar means divide the sum by the total number of summands.

Comment: So to clarify, is this correct: $\bar{y}_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}= \frac{y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}}{n^3}$ ?

Comment: $n^3$ is for CRD, not for Latin square. For Latin square, it is $n^2$.  Please read your textbook more carefully and ponder the model structure for more time before jumping to math details.

Comment: I think the confusion here is with the notation, not the actual model structure. I am studying for a course that does not use this notation and so I am trying to understand the textbook in the context of my course. I understand that there are $n^2$ observations in total (as it is an $n$x$n$ grid). The reason I asked above if it would be divided by $n^3$ is because it is a triple sum and so there will be $n^3$ terms in the full expansion @Zhanxiong

Comment: So in line with your response, am I correct to assume that $\bar{y}_{\cdot \cdot \cdot} = \frac{y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}}{n^2}$ and $\bar{y}_{ \cdot \cdot} = \frac{y_{\cdot \cdot}}{n^2}$ is the correct interpretation of the notation? (the textbook only explicitly defines the notation for a single sum so I am having to try to understand how it works for multiple sums without the book) @Zhanxiong

Comment: Remember, it's not a complete design when you are supposed to use $n^3;$ as  
Zhanxiong said, it is for CRD.

Comment: @FD_bfa I added a new proof that used direct substitution.  You can take a look.  Again, the tricky part is how to get the correct forms of $y_{i..}$ and $y_{...}$ based on the special Latin squares structure.  The algebra following is almost trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are reading the textbook *Design and Analysis of Experiments* (8th edition) by Douglas Montgomery, although the model for the Latin squares design is formally written as (note that the notations in the cited textbook were kept unchanged in equation $(1)$. It is obvious that $\alpha, \beta, \tau, p$ in $(1)$ correspond to $R, C, T, n$ in your question):
\begin{align}
y_{ijk} = \mu + \alpha_i + \tau_j + \beta_k + \epsilon_{ijk}
\begin{cases}
i = 1, 2, \ldots, p \\
j = 1, 2, \ldots, p \\
k = 1, 2, \ldots, p
\end{cases}, \tag{1}
\end{align}
which seems no different from the main-effects only model for the three-factor factorial design (admittedly, this representation could have been made less ambiguous$^\dagger$), there is an important note below this equation:

> *Because there is only one observation in each cell, only two of the three subscripts $i, j, k$ are needed to denote a particular observation. This is a consequence of each treatment appearing exactly once in each row and column.*

Therefore, instead of interpreting $y_{i..}$ as $\sum_{j = 1}^p\sum_{k = 1}^py_{ijk}$, it should be interpreted as row sum of the $i$-th row, meaning it is the sum of $p$ summands rather than $p^2$.  Keeping this in mind, as well as the constraints $\alpha_. = \beta_. = \tau_. = 0$, model $(1)$ entails:

\begin{align}
& y_{i..} = p\mu + p\alpha_i + \tau_. + \beta_. + \epsilon_{i..} 
= p\mu + p\alpha_i + \epsilon_{i..}, \\
& y_{...} = \sum_{i = 1}^p y_{i..} = p^2\mu + p\alpha_. + \epsilon_{...}
= p^2\mu + \epsilon_{...}.  \tag{2}
\end{align}

Since $\epsilon_{i..} \sim N(0, p\sigma^2), \epsilon_{...} \sim N(0, p^2\sigma^2)$, it follows that $E[\epsilon_{i..}^2] = p\sigma^2$, $E[\epsilon_{...}^2] = p^2\sigma^2$, hence $(2)$ implies that (all the cross-product terms between the random error and the fixed effect have expected value $0$ because $E[\epsilon_{i..}] = E[\epsilon_{...}] = 0$):
\begin{align}
& E(y_{i..}^2) = p^2\mu^2 + p^2\alpha_i^2 + 2p^2\mu\alpha_i + p\sigma^2, \\
& E(y_{...}^2) = p^4\mu^2 + p^2\sigma^2. \tag{3}
\end{align}

Substitute $(3)$ back to $E[SS_{\text{rows}}] = \frac{1}{p}\sum_{i = 1}^pE[y_{i..}^2] - \frac{1}{p^2}E[y_{...}^2]$ and use $\alpha_. = 0$, it follows that
\begin{align}
 & E[SS_{\text{rows}}] = \frac{1}{p}\sum_{i = 1}^p(p^2\mu^2 + p^2\alpha_i^2 + 2p^2\mu\alpha_i + p\sigma^2) - \frac{1}{p^2}(p^4\mu^2 + p^2\sigma^2) \\
=& p\sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_i^2 + p\sigma^2 - \sigma^2 \\
=& (p - 1)\sigma^2 + p\sum_{i = 1}^p\alpha_i^2, 
\end{align}
as desired.

---

$^\dagger$ For example, a better representation can be:
\begin{align}
y_{ik} = \mu + \alpha_i + \tau_{L(i, k)} + \beta_k + \epsilon_{ik}
\begin{cases}
i = 1, 2, \ldots, p \\
k = 1, 2, \ldots, p
\end{cases}, 
\end{align}
where $L$ is the Latin square (which is an order $k$ matrix) selected for the experiment. See also [this link](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat503/lesson/4/4.3).

Comment: That's a straight forward derivation (+1). And yes, Montgomery could have adhered to a better representation of the model to emphasize the overindexing as done by, say, Christensen in his book.

Comment: @User1865345 You can provide more detailed information of this book (title, page number) for interested readers.

Comment: Thanks. I assume $SS_{\text{rows}}$ corresponds to $S_{\text{rows}}$ in the question?

Comment: Yes, I kept all the notations to be consistent with the book I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer (+1). I’ve just had a chance to properly go through it and it all makes sense to me. I’m probably just missing some straight forward ideas with the other answer, but this one has been easier to understand from my perspective

Answer (score 4):

The model you described is LSD.

Here $$ S^2_R = n\sum_i\left(\bar{y}_{i\cdot\cdot}- \bar{y}_{\cdot\cdot\cdot} \right)^2.$$

Then

\begin{align}\mathbb E\left[S^2_R\right] &= \mathbb E\left[n\sum_i\left(R_i + \bar{\varepsilon}_{i\cdot\cdot} - \bar{\varepsilon}_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}\right)^2\right]\\ &= n\left[\sum_iR_i^2+\mathbb E\left\{\sum_i(\bar{\varepsilon}_{i\cdot\cdot} - \bar{\varepsilon}_{\cdot\cdot\cdot})^2\right\} + 2\underbrace{\sum_i\alpha_i\mathbb E(\bar{\varepsilon}_{i\cdot\cdot} - \bar{\varepsilon}_{\cdot\cdot\cdot})}_{=0}\right]\\ &= n\left[\sum_iR_i^2+\mathbb E\left\{\sum_i\bar{\varepsilon}^2_{i\cdot\cdot} - n\cdot \bar{\varepsilon}^2_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}\right\} \right] \\ &= n\left[\sum_iR_i^2 + \sum_i\frac{\sigma^2} n - \frac{\sigma^2}n\right] \\ &= n\sum_i R_i^2 + (n-1)\sigma^2.\end{align}

Comment: The notations are universal; so I didn't elaborate them. But if needed, would do that.

Comment: Where did this step at the beginning come from? $\mathbb E(S^2_R) = \mathbb E(n\sum_i (R_i + \bar{\varepsilon}_{i\cdot\cdot} - \bar{\varepsilon}_{\cdot\cdot\cdot})^2)$

Comment: This isn't a direct substitution of $S^2_R$ into the expectation, so I assume there were some rearragenement / substitution here?

Comment: This follows from the model equation: $y_{i\cdot\cdot} = n\mu + nR_i + \sum C_j + \sum T_k + \varepsilon_{i\cdot\cdot}.$

Comment: Doesn't the model equation imply $y_{i\cdot\cdot} = n^2 \mu + n^2R_i + n \sum C_j + n \sum T_k + \varepsilon_{i\cdot\cdot}$ because there are two sums?

Comment: No. There are $n$ observations in the $i$th row.

Comment: Your last comment echoed my comment under the question.  Do not mechanically do math before really understanding what Latin square design is! The $j, k$ under the sum sign do not vary independently (again, that was for CRD).

Comment: Okay, (I think) I get it now. Because each treatment can only appear once in a given column (and row), the sum will only have $n$ terms as each treatment only corresponds to one treatment in a given column (or row)

Comment: Good, now you really get it.  After it, even with direct substitution, you shall arrive the desired result.

Comment: Regarding your answer @User1865345 : I'm not seeing how the formula you start with for $S^2_R$ is equal to the one posted in the question ($S^2_{\text{row}} = \sum _ {i=1}^n \frac{Y_{i \cdot \cdot}^2}{n} - \frac{Y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}^2}{n^2}$). I understand everything you have done, but I can't see how these are both equivalent definitions

Comment: @FD_bfa, expand the square. You would reach the same form.

Comment: Use the summation part. Also where did $n^4$ come from? Won't it be $n^2$?

Comment: Again you are mistaking. In $i$th row, there are $n$ observations. So $\bar{y}_{i \cdot \cdot} = \frac{y_{i \cdot \cdot}}{n}.$

Comment: What I mean is: $n ( \bar{y}_{i\cdot\cdot}- \bar{y}_{\cdot\cdot\cdot})^2 = n (\frac{y_{i \cdot \cdot}}{n} - \frac{y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}}{n^2})^2 = \frac{y^2_{i \cdot \cdot}}{n}+\frac{y^2_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}}{n^3}$. This is slightly different to the form in the question because the denominator is $n^3$ in the second term in the sum

Comment: . . . instead of the denominator being $n^2$ @User1865345

Comment: @FD_bfa Observe $\sum (\bar y^2_{i\cdot\cdot}-2\bar y_{i\cdot\cdot}\bar y_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}+\bar y^2_{\cdot\cdot\cdot})=n\sum \bar y^2_{i\cdot\cdot}-2\bar y_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}\sum_i\bar y_{i\cdot\cdot}+n\bar y_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}^2= \frac{y_{i\cdot\cdot}^2}n-2ny_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}^2+ny_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}^2.$ Also, in the formula $S^2_{\text{row}}, $ it would be $Y^2_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}/n.$

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies it. And is $y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot} = \mu^2  + n \sum_i R_i + \sum _j C_j+ \sum _k T_k + \epsilon _{\cdot \cdot \cdot}$ ?

Comment: $y_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$ is the grand total of all the $n^2$ observations.

Comment: When you conclude that  $n\sum_i\left(\bar{y}_{i\cdot\cdot}- \bar{y}_{\cdot\cdot\cdot} \right)^2 = n\sum_i (R_i + \bar{\varepsilon}_{i\cdot\cdot} - \bar{\varepsilon}_{\cdot\cdot\cdot})^2$, what expression for $y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot}$ did you use to get it into this form? @User1865345

Comment: ^ it's still the step from the first line of math to the second line that I'm struggling with. How does it simplify to that form? The working in the link above seems to be wrong but I can't see why. @User1865345

Comment: You wrote it almost correctly but in place of $\mu^2, $ it would have been $n^2\mu$ and keep in mind that $\sum R_i=\sum C_j=\sum T_k=0.$

Comment: Thanks for all your help

Comment: In the 3rd last line, where did the $-n \bar{\epsilon}$ come from? I’m not seeing that term when I expand the brackets @User1865345

Comment: @FD_bfa, it is $n\varepsilon^2_{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$ and it follows in the same way by expanding the square like in one of my earlier comments.

Comment: In your answer there is a bar over the epsilon @User1865345

Comment: Yes, the bar is included. @FD_bfa.